# How to calculate a surface integral using Gauss' Divergence theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following:

$$\iint_S F\cdot n~dS$$ given $S$ is defined to be the surface area of the cylinder given by $$x^2+y^2 \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq 1$$ and $$F(x,y,z)=(x^2y,z-xy^2,z^2)$$ using Divergence theorem I know that $$\iint_S F\cdot n~dS=\iiint_R \operatorname{div}(F)~dV$$.

I then calculated $\operatorname{div}(F)=2y$ but then I'm a little stuck. I want to evaluate $$\iiint_R 2y~dx~dy~dz$$. But go stuck here, I decided to continue on and switched into polar co-ordinates seeing as I couldn't figure out the limits of integration in Cartesian so I then calulated.

$$\iiint_R 2y~dx~dy~dz=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^12r\sin\theta~dr~d\theta~ dz$$ which evaluated to give $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^12r\sin\theta~dr~d\theta~dz=0$$ so then $$\iint_S F\cdot n~dS=0$$ but I'm very unsure about my workings. Shouldn't I have multiplied by $r$ when changing to polars because of the Jacobian matrix?

So maybe should I be evaluating  $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^12r^2\sin\theta~dr~d\theta~dz$$ to get me what I want?

Comment: $\mathop{\mathrm{div}} F = 2z$

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part. Could you comment on the rest though. (Assuming I wrote $z$)

Comment: Answer is $\pi$?

Comment: Would I just be able to do $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2z drd\theta dz$$? Or would I need to multiply by $r$ because of the Jacobian. 

The answer would be $\pi$ if I evaluated this integral but I'm not sure whether it should be  $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2zr~ drd\theta dz$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\nabla \cdot \vec F=2z$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F dV&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(2z)r\,dr\,d\theta \,dz\\\\
&=\pi
\end{align}$$

where we have used the transformation $dx\,dy\,dz\to r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$

---

**NOTE:**

The $\hat y$ component of $\vec F$ is $F_y=z-xy^2$.  We remark that the result $\oint_S \vec F\cdot \hat n\,dS=\pi$ is unchanged upon replacing $z$ in $F_y$ with any differentiable function of $z$.  That is, if $F_y\to g(z)-xy^2$, where $g$ is differentiable, then $\nabla \cdot \vec F=2z$ is unaltered and thus

$$\oint_S \vec F\cdot \hat n\,dS=\int_V\,\nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV=\pi$$$$

Comment: Okay so I need to multiply by $r$ because of the Jacobian? Your edit answered my question thanks. Also is it common to drop the $3$ integral sign it gets tiring writing them.

Comment: @BarryA Yes, that is correct!  Well done recognizing that.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer I will vote this as best when it lets me.

Comment: Wow! Thanks.  And you're quite welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You show that integral equal to
$$
I = \iiint_R 2z\,dxdydz.
$$
You may evaluate it in cartesian coordinates:
$$
I = \int\limits_{x^2 + y^2\le 1} dxdy \cdot \int_0^1 2z\,dz = \pi\cdot 1 = \pi
$$